# Are there any scientific papers that were retracted by the publisher due to the reader comments?

Tags: retraction

Recently, Elsevier retracted an article [that was published in 2012](https://retractionwatch.com/2020/06/17/elsevier-journal-to-retract-2012-paper-widely-derided-as-racist/).
The only explanation by the publisher is as follows:

> Personality and Individual Differences has taken the decision to
> retract the review article Rushton, J.P., Templer, D.I. (2012). Do
> pigmentation and the melanocortin system modulate aggression and
> sexuality in humans as they do in other animals? Personality and
> Individual Differences, 53, 4-8. This retraction comes after a
> thorough review of the published article, the sources cited within the
> article, and critical comments from readers. The retraction notice is
> currently being finalized and will appear in the journal imminently.

As far as I know, if an article contains misinformation, the right practice is to publish a refutation article at the same journal.

I wonder whether there are other examples which the publisher retracts an article **because of the sources cited within the article, and critical comments from readers.**

Comment: Where is your source for “the right practice is to publish a refutation article”? Is that your opinion or the publisher’s policy?

Comment: Given the politically sensitive nature of the contents of the article, it sounds to me like the publisher would use any excuse to retract it, regardless of the truthfulness of its contents.

Comment: @SolarMike *As far as I know*, if a study is published, there should be at least one other article with conflicting results to disregard the first one. And I am pretty sure "critical comments from readers" is not a reason to do so.

Comment: @padawan Why would e.g. retractions based on data fabrication (often found by readers) require a refutation article to be published first?

Comment: @Anyon or based on cherry-picked references for that matter.

Comment: @Anyon I don't think data fabrication falls under the same category. When detected, it can be easily shown that the data was fabricated by writing a short letter. And the reason would be "data fabrication" not "reader comments."

Comment: @henning--reinstateMonica I honestly don't understand when is meant by "cherry-picked references." Isn't this what we **must** do while writing an article, instead of dumping every related study?

Comment: @padawan Cherry-picking refers to a biased sample, choosing only papers that support a specific view and ignoring those that refute it. One does not need to "dump" every related study, but if you conspicuously avoid references conflicting with the claims of your paper there is no need for a "new paper" to refute it: it's already been done.

Comment: "comes after" and "because of" are different, so this question is unclear.

Comment: I suggest you do some reading at the [Retraction Watch](http://retractionwatch.wordpress.com/) blog. "critical comments from readers" are nowadays called "post-publication review".

Comment: I am closing this question because: 1) Taken literally, it asks for a list with no best answer. 2) The next best question is whether this is commonly accepted practice, however, until the retraction notice is published, it is not clear what *this* is. 3) Even then, the question must outline clear criteria on the answers to avoid being overrun with people sharing their opinion on the retraction.

Comment: On a completely different note, please be aware the article in question is a review article. In this context, cherry-picking references is indeed comparable to data fabrication.

Comment: [Meta discussion on this question](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4735/7734)

Comment: I voted to reopen, but I think you should really specify what you mean by "critical comments from readers". Isn't every retraction at some point triggered by critical comments from readers unless the authors themselves discover their mistake?

Comment: I've never heard of any practice that requires a "refutation article" when an article would otherwise need to be retracted.